# Default username and password for TFS2010 installed as localhost

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Merry Christmas everyone !

I've installed Team Foundation Server 2010 with advanced configuration but I left the settings as default (like Service Account: NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE and others)...

All good until when I typed `http://localhost:8080/tfs` and there it asks me to provide username and password.

What is the default username and password ? I didn't provide any username and/or password during configuration.

I typed as my Windows account name but it doesn't work.

Help me please...

Thank you

EDIT:  Please watch my short video capture: http://youtu.be/i8C5mp7fUsA

Comment: do u have a password for your windows account ? if not then create one .

Comment: I set up the password. Huh, I passed the login box but the page is loading until showing time out message error.

Comment: strange behaviour ..is anything else running on 8080 ?

Comment: I changed the port to 1000 for example but same behaviour...I want to be sure that port 8080 is not used by another software/service

Comment: can you help me via TeamViewer please ? thank you

Comment: yeah definitly it works using your windows account, but in my case I have my hotmail email account linked to my windows.. so, I just used my email address and the password for this, I am sharing below an screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS uses Window's accounts for its permissions. If you're logging in on a workstation setup, rather than one linked to AD then remember you need to specify your machine name as part of the username, for example MACHINE\michaels.

In order to setup new projects you will need to first start off using an administrator account - if your normal username isn't a Windows administrator, then login using your admin username and password (you can then grant permissions to your normal account. You can also use the Windows security groups on the machine to add yourself - there will be a local group called "Team Foundation Administrators". [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253077.aspx) has a list of the Windows groups you can configure.

Comment: please check my video capture to understand better my problem...I am administrator but ... no result

Answer (score 2):

it is the windows login , password and u can set it in the administration panel also .

UPDATE - mine was ashutosh-pc\ashutosh and my windows password

Answer (score 0):

You have set your service account to LOCAL SERVICE. Please change this to NETWORK SERVICE. The login box you are getting is not to login TFS, but to get access to your machine resources. The LOCAL SERVICE account does not have enough permissions to operate TFS.

If you don't have NETWORK SERVICE, then use a regular windows account.

See for more information the [TFS 2010 Install Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24337).

Comment: see here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvRS9NGlgCw and you will see that page is loading until timeout.

Comment: The problem is thus not in TFS, but in Web Access only. Did you check the aplication pool for Web Access?

Comment: If I change Identity to `Network Service` then the error appears: http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/9389/14292975.png ... But everything is OK (the port, IP address an others)

Comment: Michael, I am so sorry that you experience this. I have done lots of TFS installations in the past, but never saw this behavior. I am unable to help you further. Did you try to post your question on the MSDN forums?

Comment: Or, can help me please with teamviewer ? please, I need that this TFS must be done for faculty...Please, please :) Add me to skype: teodorescu.mihail81. Thank you

Comment: Why not create a new VM and install TFS again?

Comment: Yes, yes, yes. I did. I cannot access the TFS web interface because of FIREWALL. My ESET blocked the localhost response to me. I've added an exception to firewall and now it is works like as charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah definitely it works using your windows account, but in my case I have my hotmail email account linked to my windows.. so, I just used my email address and the password for this, I am sharing an screenshot, this is the firs default page after logged in.

[image]